# Firebase NodeJs OrderByChild

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I want to have my list sorted alphabetically by the child name 'name'.  Currently this is the Server file I am using to render the page:

```
app.get('/testpage', function (request, response) {
    var testDBref = database.ref('testdb')

    testDBref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
        var result = snapshot.val()
        if (!result) {
            result = {}
        };
        response.render('TestPage.ejs', { 
            items: result, 
            pageTitle: "My Lists"
        });
    });
});
```

However, when I do the following:

```
app.get('/testpage2', function (request, response) {
    var testDBref2 = database.ref('testdb').orderByChild('name')
    testDBref2 .once('value', function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(child){
            console.log(child.val()) // NOW THE CHILDREN PRINT IN ORDER
            var result = snapshot.child('name').snapshot.key
            response.render('testpage2.ejs', { 
                items: result, 
                pageTitle: "My Lists"
            });
        });
    });
});
```

It errors out saying: cannot set headers after they are sent to the client, req.next is not a function.

When I just have it console to the log:

```
app.get('/testpage2', function (request, response) {
    var testDBref2 = database.ref('testdb').orderByChild('name')
    testDBref2 .once('value', function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(child){
            console.log(child.val())
        });
    });
});
```

It is sorted alphabetically in json (but of course it doesn't display in the web page).  I'm new to the nosql db's so any assistance would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the keys in the order of the `name` property, you will have to use the `forEach` operator. That's because the order of keys in a JSON object is undefined, but most JSON processors will return them alphabetically.

But as you also found, you can only call `response.render` once, so if you want to return multiple child nodes, you'll have to render them outside of the `forEach` loop.

The solution is to convert the child nodes to an array, and (if needed) put the key of each child node in the object in the array. For example:

```
app.get('/testpage2', function (request, response) {
    var testDBref2 = database.ref('testdb').orderByChild('name')
    testDBref2 .once('value', function (snapshot) {
        var result = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(child){
            result.push({ key: child.key, name: child.child('name').val() });
        });
        response.render('testpage2.ejs', { 
            items: result, 
            pageTitle: "My Lists"
        });
    });
});
```